# How to change button to infinite scroll with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button class named ' getmore'. first script works fine.Now how can i add this inside window.scroll  function for infinite scroll.   please help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.getmore',function(){
        var lastelement = $(this ).attr('id');
        $.ajax({        
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getmore.php',
            data:'lastelement=' + lastelement,
            beforesend: function() {
                $('.getmore').html('loading....');
            },   
            success: function(data){
                $('.getmore').remove();
                $('#recs') .append(data) ; 
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I think this is what you needed

While scroll is at bottom, load content from server.

```
function LoadContent() {
  var resultString = $("#contentDiv").html();
  $(jsonObj).each(function(i, e) {
    for (j = 1; j < 101; j++) {
      resultString += "No: " + j + ", Name: " + e.Name + ", Age: " + e.Age + "<br/>";
    }
  });
  $("#contentDiv").html(resultString);
}
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    LoadContent();
  }
});
```

Please check the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn0sLjn6/)